I want to show a message on UI while suitlet is processing after click on button until it's processed
I've created a UI using SL, on which I'm getting many transactions, Let's suppose I've selected 10 number of transactions and I submit the form, let me be clear the buttons are custom approve JE or reject i've created my functions for that in client script attached in the sl, Now I want to show any kind of message which will indicate that record's are processing after click on the buttons Of approve or reject, until the record processed so User can understand and wait until record processed.
I'm new for this approach, I need suggestion to implement the things to work proper.

Rather than posting directly to your Suitelet you could do the following:

add some unique html to each selectable transaction. You'll need to be able to manipulate that with normal DOM methods.
in your Suitelet code that handles get requests check for an 'action' parameter. If that parameter exists treat the request as client call and return JSON.
Instead of using a submit button on your form use a regular button that calls a client script.
Calling the client script will:

collect the id of the transaction being approved
manipulate the DOM to show the transaction is in process
use the https.get.promise method to submit the approval asynchronously
show the approval status when the promise returns.



the core of your click handler might look something like the following. The setStatus function will depend on how you are laying out the transactions to approve (e.g. could be updating a text column on a List type sublist):
setStatus(transactionId, 'submitting');

var actionURL = url.resolveScript({
    scriptId: 'customscript_approve_tran_sl', // your suitelet's script and deployment ids
    deploymentId: 'customdeploy_approve_tran_sl',
    params: {
        action:'approve',
        custparam_id: transactionid
    }
});

http.get.promise({url:actionURL}).then(resp=>{
    const data = JSON.parse(resp.body);
    if(data.succes){
        setStatus(transactionId, 'Approved');

    }else{
        setStatus(transactionId, data.message || 'Not Approved');
    }
});

